# For $p$ a global type, $p$ divides iff it forks

Tags: logic, model-theory

I am trying to solve the exercise problem of showing

> A global type $p$ forks if and only if it divides.

I believe this exercise shows up in many places, including Tent and Ziegler:

> (Exercise 7.1.3.  Let $p$ be a type over the model $M$ and $A \subseteq M$.  Assume that $M$ is $|A|^+$-saturated.  Show that $p$ forks over $A$ if and only if $p$ divides over $A$.

The book kindly offers an answer to the problem, but it has apparent typos, and I can't fix it.

I appreciate any clues to this problem.  In particular: is this just a fact about ultrafilters, ideals, and elements that generate ideals in a Boolean algebra (here, this will be the Boolean algebra of definable subsets of the monster)?  Or do I actually need to use the definition of dividing?

Comment: I agree that the solution to Exercise 7.1.3 in Tent and Ziegler contains three obvious typos: it should say "which implies a *disjunction* of formulas ... which *divide* over $A$. Choose a tuple... the formulas $\varphi_i(x,b')$ *divide* over $A$, and one of them belongs to $p$." Does this solve the problem for you? If not, what step is unclear?

Comment: @AlexKruckman So $b'$ is supposed to realize the type of $b$ over $Am$, where $b$ is the parameters of the formulas that divide and $m$ is the parameter(s) of the formula in $p$.  But isn't that type already realized by $b$?

Comment: Right, this is a point that could definitely be explained better: $b'$ might be outside of $\mathbb{M}$ (i.e. In a bigger monster model).

Comment: I know - the monster model is supposed to contain *all* elements we care about. But when you talk about global types, it's often useful to have the monster sitting inside an even bigger monster. Talking about the distinction between forking and dividing is one of these times, since this distinction is all about whether you can *extend* types to larger parameter sets in a non-dividing way.

Comment: @AlexKruckman  Thank you for your comments.  Does the following make sense: $M$ can play the role of a smaller monster, and $\mathfrak C$, the sufficiently saturated model Tent and Ziegler fixed in the background, is the bigger monster here. (I had assumed that Tent and Ziegler's $M$ played the role of the monster here, but I might have been wrong.)

Comment: In the statement of the exercise, I think $M$ is just any sufficiently saturated model, right? Then yes, you should think of it sitting inside the monster. Of course, you can apply the result of the exercise to the monster model too, since it's very saturated!

Comment: @AlexKruckman Also, is the following plausible:  even though the type of $b$ over $Am$ is already realized in $M$, it helps to take another realizer $b'$ outside $M$, the existence of which is guaranteed by the $|M|^+$-saturation of $\mathfrak C$.

Comment: Now I think things are getting confused. I'll write a full answer later (I'm on my phone now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In light of your previous question about parameters, let's clarify the definition of forking. Let $\mathfrak{C}$ be a monster model of our theory $T$, and let $A\subseteq \mathfrak{C}$ be a small set.

**Definition:** A formula with parameters from $\mathfrak{C}$ forks over $A$ if and only if it implies a disjunction $\bigvee_{i=1}^n \varphi_i(x,c_i)$, such that each formula $\varphi_i(x,c_i)$ divides over $A$. If $A\subseteq B$, then a complete type $p(x)$ in $S(B)$ forks over $A$ if and only if it contains a formula which forks over $A$.

In the above definition, the parameters $c_i$ can be any tuples from $\mathfrak{C}$. Even when we're talking about a type $p(x)\in S(B)$, the $c_i$ need not come from $B$. In fact, the definition would be pretty silly if we required the $c_i$ to be in $B$. Why?

**Observation:** Whenever a complete type contains a disjunction, it must contain one of the disjuncts. So if $p(x)\in S(B)$ forks over $A$, witnessed by a disjunction $\bigvee_{i=1}^n \varphi_i(x,c_i)$ with all of the parameters $c_i$ in $B$, then $p(x)$ contains the disjunction, so $p(x)$ contains some $\varphi_i(x,c_i)$, so $p(x)$ already divides over $A$.

The reason we need arbitrary parameters from $\mathfrak{C}$ (i.e. why we need the notions of forking and dividing to possibly be different for complete types) is that the point of this definition is to get nonforking extensions to larger parameter sets. The set of formulas with parameters from $\mathfrak{C}$ which divide over $A$ is not necessarily an ideal, but the set of formulas with parameters from $\mathfrak{C}$ which fork over $A$ is an ideal. It follows that any type $p(x)\in S(B)$ which does not fork over $A$ has a global extension in $S(\mathfrak{C})$ which does not fork over $A$, and hence (by restricting) an extension in $S(C)$ which does not fork over $A$ for any $B\subseteq C$.

OK, now for your actual question. Suppose $M\models T$ is $|A|^+$-saturated, $A\subseteq M$, and $p(x)\in S(M)$.

**Claim:** $p(x)$ divides over $A$ if and only if it forks over $A$.

*Proof:* Dividing easily implies forking, so suppose $p(x)$ forks over $A$. Then it contains a formula $\psi(x,m)$ with parameters from $M$ such that $\mathfrak{C}\models \forall x\, (\psi(x,m)\rightarrow \bigvee_{i=1}^n \varphi_i(x,c_i))$ and each $\varphi_i(x,c_i)$ divides over $A$. We may as well assume the $c_i$ are all the same finite tuple $c$ (by adding unmentioned parameters to each $\varphi_i$). Since $M$ is $|A|^+$-saturated, we can find $c'\in M$ such that $\text{tp}(c'/Am) = \text{tp}(c/Am)$. Now:

- $\text{tp}(c'/m) = \text{tp}(c/m)$ implies that $\mathfrak{C}\models \forall x\, (\psi(x,m)\rightarrow \bigvee_{i=1}^n \varphi_i(x,c'))$.
- $\text{tp}(c'/A) = \text{tp}(c/A)$ implies that each $\varphi_i(x,c')$ divides over $A$.

And since the parameters $c'$ are in $M$, $p(x)$ divides over $A$ by the **Observation**. $\square$

Now since $\mathfrak{C}$ itself is $|A|^+$ saturated for any small $A$, you can apply the **Claim** with $M = \mathfrak{C}$ to get the conclusion that a global type forks over a small set if and only if it divides over that set. But if we make the standard assumption that all objects we'll ever consider are already in $\mathfrak{C}$, then this is a trivial remark, by the **Observation** (there simply are no parameters outside of $\mathfrak{C}$). Of course, the fact that we can make this standard assumption boils down to the proof of the claim: the behavior of any extra parameters we could ever want can already be realized inside $\mathfrak{C}$.

As I alluded to in the comments, there are situations where it is convenient (but not strictly necessary) to instead imagine that there's a whole heirarchy of monster models, so we can always move to a bigger one if we want to. This is like how it can be foundationally convenient to assume a proper class of inaccessible cardinals instead of just assuming one or working in NBG.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  If we forget the version of the problem in Tent and Ziegler, could it be the case that "a global type forks iff divides" just because of your *Observation*, if we assume that there is a single monster over which that global type is and from which we take parameters for the disjuncts?  (I understand that you are suggesting that that perspective is not what is commonly used in model theory.)

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I'm saying in my second-to-last paragraph ("This is a trivial remark, by the Observation"). And on the contrary, the assumption (the "standard assumption") that all parameters come from a single monster model *is* commonly used in model theory. As I say in the last paragraph, it's occasionally (but rarely) convenient to change perspectives.